# Add value to nested dictionaries

Tags: c#

If I have:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<int, int>>();
```

How can I add values to the nested Dictionaries. What is the proper syntax to do that?

```
dict.Add(...)
```

I am aware of the syntax for >. But not for two nested dictionaries in one.

Comment: Can you please specify why you have decided to have a Dictionary as key value?

Comment: Using a dictionary as a key for a dictionary doesn't make any sense.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that using a dictionary as a key for another dictionary makes much sense..

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

dict.Add(dict1, dict2);

or 

dict.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(), new Dictionary<int, int>());
```

or with some data using [initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer)

```
dict.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "test", "test"} }, new Dictionary<int, int>() { {1, 1}});
```